# Determining company name from IP address

Tags: geolocation, ip, ip-address, whois

I apologize for the broad question. But I have a list of IP addresses, and would like to connect them to the companies they came from.

I'm not interested in identifying personal IP address information (probably not even possible) but I figure there must be a way to identify if the IP address is associated with a large corporation.

Whois.net usually only gives the ISP name, not the company name.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest trying out Ipregistry (disclaimer: I run the service): https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout

Comment: I would suggest to use my service https://smartip.io, we expose this information in the asn -> organization field of our API response: https://api.smartip.io/?api_key=E92293BF-60DE-42CF-941D-C9206C26F9D1

Answer (score 11):

The http://ipinfo.io API (my own service) returns the company name as the org field:

```
$ curl http://ipinfo.io/198.252.206.16
{
  "ip": "198.252.206.16",
  "hostname": "stackoverflow.com",
  "city": null,
  "region": null,
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "38.0000,-97.0000",
  "org": "AS25791 Stack Exchange, Inc."
}
```

You can get just that field by adding /org to the URL:

```
$ curl http://ipinfo.io/198.252.206.16/org
AS25791 Stack Exchange, Inc.
```

You can combine this with some other commands to do a bulk lookup of all of your IPs and see what company they belong to:

```
$ cat ips.txt | xargs -I% curl -s http://ipinfo.io/%/org | paste ips.txt -
198.252.206.16  AS25791 Stack Exchange, Inc.
173.252.110.27  AS32934 Facebook, Inc.
74.125.239.132  AS15169 Google Inc.
206.190.36.45   AS36647 Yahoo
```

You can find out more details about the API at http://ipinfo.io/developers.

Comment: Hi, Just sent you an e-mail via your contact us page on http://ipinfo.io, but wanted to address it here/add some detail - When visiting http://ipinfo.io and putting in an IP address, the next page doesn't update the URL bar with that IP address, allowing easy sharing of the info on that result page via a link with others. URL updates do happen on other pages (Like the Network Details page). Hopefully this can be changed to make your service more useful to more people.

Comment: Lol, you actually suggested a service which costs 999$/month. :D

Comment: @OzanKurt it's free for up to 1000 req/api, if you just want the ASN name. For more detailed company details (like when you want to identify a small business that's a customer of an ISP, and the ASN details show the ISP) then yeah, you'll need our Pro plan, which is currently priced at $999/month.

Comment: Hi Ben. How does ipinfo.io get the information in the "company" field (name, domain, type etc.), how do you verify that information, and how can an organisation correct malicious/defamatory information in that field?

Comment: @toryan we have a whole data team that works on this data! You can submit corrections/feedback on the data to support@ipinfo.io

Answer (score 1):

[ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-19747074&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) provides an API endpoint (https://api.ipdata.co) that provides such information (I run this service)

Ipdata has 10 endpoints around the world each able to handle >800M calls daily!

```
curl https://api.ipdata.co/70.70.70.70?api-key=test
```

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-19747074-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

Gives

```
{
    "ip": "70.70.70.70",
    "is_eu": false,
    "city": "",
    "region": "",
    "region_code": "",
    "country_name": "Canada",
    "country_code": "CA",
    "continent_name": "North America",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "latitude": 43.6319,
    "longitude": -79.3716,
    "asn": "AS6327",
    "organisation": "Shaw Communications Inc.",
    "postal": "",
    "calling_code": "1",
    "flag": "https://ipdata.co/flags/ca.png",
    "emoji_flag": "\ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udde6",
    "emoji_unicode": "U+1F1E8 U+1F1E6",
    "languages": [
        {
            "name": "English",
            "native": "English"
        },
        {
            "name": "French",
            "native": "Fran\u00e7ais"
        }
    ],
    "currency": {
        "name": "Canadian Dollar",
        "code": "CAD",
        "symbol": "CA$",
        "native": "$",
        "plural": "Canadian dollars"
    },
    "time_zone": {
        "name": "",
        "abbr": "",
        "offset": "",
        "is_dst": "",
        "current_time": ""
    },
    "threat": {
        "is_tor": false,
        "is_proxy": false,
        "is_anonymous": false,
        "is_known_attacker": false,
        "is_known_abuser": false,
        "is_threat": false,
        "is_bogon": false
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying out [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service).

Ipregistry returns company data along with the company domain name when available. You also get IP type classification, many more data such as threat data that allows detecting and preventing fraud.

For a quick try, just open the next link in your browser:

https://api.ipregistry.co/198.252.206.16?key=tryout&pretty=true

Comment: Providing details of the company using an IP would be more useful and possibly what the OP is interested in. For example, your service gives fastly for 151.101.65.195 and 151.101.1.195, not anything that indicates that it's your service.

Comment: IP Geolocation is not an exact science with 100% accuracy. The example you give with `151.101.65.195` and `151.101.1.195` is one of these exceptions where it is not possible to determine the final end company since the IP address is used by a hosting provider as a load balancing entry point. This applies to any IP Geolocation service (including the one above) so the downvote is not really fair. Please note that with Ipregistry you can know the company returned is not the end company by checking the IP type classification (e.g. hosting).

Comment: In general it's rather *inaccurate*, and if a netblock is for an ISP, typical IP to company mapping isn't always going to be of use; it will serve to find who to contact in an abuse case, and your service is great for that, but not (for example) if wanting to dynamically tailor web page content based on knowledge of who a visitor *actually is*, which is what the OP was asking about. I can't recall downvoting but if I did it's because services such as ipregistry don't correctly address the question that the OP presented.

Comment: I understand and agree that IP geolocation is not appropriate for all use cases. However, you should read again the op question who wants to identify large companies based on IP addresses. Such companies have most of the time their own ASN... It's also weird you made your comment on my answer and not on the top voted answers who suffer from the exact same issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IP address you can go to [who.is](http://who.is) and enter the IP. If you then scroll down you will find a feild where it says "OrgName:" and there you got it :)

Here is a image of when I did a search on 74.125.228.72 (youtube.com owned by Google):[image: who.is]